# c# oneway element binding update on lost focus

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have an assignment where I need to oneway bind to build a name but the full name is built every time one of the textboxes loses focus. updateSourceTrigger=LostFocus doesn't work since it's nog twoway binding.
is there a possibility to do this using oneway?

```
<Window x:Class="name_binder.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:name_binder"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="575">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBox Name="firstNameTextBox" Margin="7.5" Height="35" FontSize="20" Text="&lt;Enter first name>" GotFocus="TextBox_gotFocus"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="LastNameTextBox" Margin="7.5" Height="35" FontSize="20" Text="&lt;Enter last name>" GotFocus="TextBox_gotFocus"></TextBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Margin="7.5" Height="35" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=firstNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                <TextBox Margin="7.5" Height="35" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=LastNameTextBox, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is WPF?

Depending on what kind of design you're using:

**One**

You could handle the `LostFocus` event:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=OneWay}" LostFocus="tb_LostFocus">
```

You'd then have access to `((TextBox)sender).Text`.

**Two**

You could use `System.Windows.Interactivity` to execute a command when the `LostFocus` event happens, passing the text as the parameter (you'll probably need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project):

```
<Window ... xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" ... >
...
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=OneWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```